# Firebase rule to allow write only for children

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to allow the family creator to add children. I´m saving the uid as the "owner" of the family

```
match /families/{family} {
  allow create: if request.auth != null
  allow update: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.uid;
}

match /families/{family}/children/{child} {
    allow read
    allow create: if request.auth.uid != null //this will allow any parent to create children on any famly!!;
}
```

how can I allow create if {family}.uid == request.auth.uid ??

Answer (score 2):

You will need to [use `get()` to access other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) other than the one being matched by the rule.  For your case, that means you need to `get()` the family document in order to use its field values.

```
match /families/{family}/children/{child} {
    allow read;
    allow create: if
      get(/databases/$(database)/documents/families/$(family)).data.uid == request.auth.uid;
}
```

Comment: cool. I thought it was a way to inherit {family} but this works. thank you!!!!